# In Dart, what different about List.unmodifiable() and UnmodifiableListView?

Tags: dart

In Dart, if want to create a unmodifiable list, it can use List.unmodifiable() or UnmodifiableListView

```
List<int> list = [1, 2, 3];
List<int> unmodifiableList = List.unmodifiable(list);
UnmodifiableListView unmodifiableListView = UnmodifiableListView(list);
```

what different about this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`List.unmodifiable` is a `List` constructor; it creates a new `List` object.  It creates a *copy* of the original `List`, and that copy cannot be mutated.  Mutating the original `List` will not affect the copy.

`UnmodifiableListView` is a wrapper (a "view") around the original `List`, and the original cannot be mutated through the `UnmodifiableListView`.  Mutations to the original `List` can still be observed in the `UnmodifiableListView`.

For example:

```dart
import 'dart:collection';

void main() {
  var originalList = [1, 2, 3];
  var unmodifiableCopy = List<int>.unmodifiable(originalList);
  var unmodifiableView = UnmodifiableListView(originalList);
  
  originalList[0] = -1;
  print('$unmodifiableCopy'); // Prints: [1, 2, 3]
  print('$unmodifiableView'); // Prints: [-1, 2, 3]
}
```

Comment: so List.unmodifiable is O(n), and UnmodifiableListView is O(1)?

Comment: In terms of construction time with respect to the number of elements in the original `List`, yes.